Merging fee tags
We have the winner fees with 35 results, and others which should be merged into that:

fee (1 result)
exchange-fees (1 result)
transaction-fees (17 results, we might merge into this one if you prefer, but I'd rather use simply "fees")


I think we should merge them all into fees. While the transaction-fees is also a good tag for discussing those fees in particular as opposed to fees charged by exchanges and what have you, I don't think there will be too much confusion.
